# FIND_IN_SET query can not work in laravel 5.7

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am finding inputted user_id in accepted_join_id above query gives error as
syntax error, unexpected '$user_id' (T_VARIABLE)

```
$query=DB::select('select activity_id,accepted_join_id from table_user_create_activity WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$user_id',?) and activity_id=?',[$user_id,$accepted_join_id]);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve by using `FIND_IN_SET`?

Comment: i will check whether user_id present in accepted_join_id list or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to inject $user_id value from php into your query try this:

```
$query=DB::select('select activity_id,accepted_join_id from table_user_create_activity WHERE FIND_IN_SET('.$user_id.',?) and activity_id=?',[$user_id,$accepted_join_id]);
```

or if $user_id is in query it should be like:

```
$query=DB::select('select activity_id,accepted_join_id from table_user_create_activity WHERE FIND_IN_SET("$user_id",?) and activity_id=?',[$user_id,$accepted_join_id]);
```